# Adjusting for time-invariant covariates in diff-in-diff using TWFE approach

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I am planning a staggered difference-in-differences analysis examining the impact of a change in health policy at the county level. The policy was implemented at different times in different counties, and in many counties not at all. I have data for many counties, with only a small fraction having ever implemented the policy.

I would like to utilize a TWFE model (I have read many of the criticisms of this approach but want to at least implement it even if it's not my final analytic model), but I'm confused about this approach because I also want to adjust my model for county-level covariates. It seems that in a TWFE model this won't be possible because any time-invariant county-level covariates will be perfectly collinear with the county-specific fixed effect, yet I keep reading sources that claim that adjusting for baseline covariates to satisfy the parallel trends assumption is a common practice in TWFE diff-in-diff ([for example](https://bcallaway11.github.io/files/Callaway-Chapter-2022/main.pdf)).

Here's an example of R code implementing the model, where Outcome is my outcome variable, TimeToTreat is the number of months before or after policy implementation, Treated is a dummy for counties that implemented the policy, Time is time of outcome measurement, and CountyID identifies counties (haha):

```
model.twfe <- feols(Outcome ~ 
                    i(TimeToTreat, Treated, ref=-1) | Time + CountyID, 
                    cluster = ~CountyID,
                    data = toy_data)
```

This seems to work as expected. However, if I try to add additional terms to the model formula that are time-invariant characteristics of the counties (e.g. region), they are automatically dropped out of the model for perfect collinearity.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The author was merely stating that evaluators will often demonstrate parallels paths by also conditioning on covariates. I don’t think there was a claim that these covariates should be *time-invariant*. Is there a specific section of that working paper that confuses you?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to understand then in general is if one wants to condition on a time-invariant covariate (like region) in order to demonstrate parallel paths, how is that possible in a TWFE framework? But perhaps I'm overthinking this and the answer is you can't, just like in any other TWFE model